# jQuery Dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, rollover

I've been able to make a jQuery drop down, however, I can't make it stay expanded when one of the child links is rolled over.

Code:

```
<li>
    <a  onmouseover="$('.dropdown-1').slideDown('medium');" href="/hosting">Why Veoloo</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-1">
        <li onmouseout="$('.dropdown-1').slideUp('medium');"><a href="#">The Reasons (15)</a></li> 
        <li onmouseout="$('.dropdown-1').slideUp('medium');"><a href="#">Customer Testimonials</a></li>
        <li onmouseout="$('.dropdown-1').slideUp('medium');"><a href="#">Our Support Scope</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html:

```
<li id="menu">
  <a href="/hosting">Why Veoloo</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-1">
    <li><a href="#">The Reasons (15)</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Customer Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Support Scope</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

javascript :

```
$(function(){
  $('.dropdown-1').hide();
  $('#menu').hover(function(){
        $('.dropdown-1').slideDown('medium');
  }, function(){
        $('.dropdown-1').slideUp('medium');
  });
})
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gurPn/1/

**[EDIT]:**
Updated to use hover method (jQuery) and trigger the hove off of the parent container (this allows the mouseleave event to be captured only on the container giving the desired drop down effect).

Comment: I liked your answer but: I noticed that the menu does not slideUp if you leave the "Why Veoloo" a tag up left or right. It will only close if you actually go down over one of the menu items.